# SQL Server group by con condicion

Tags: sql-server

El siguiente código me trae como resultado un listado de elementos con su cantidad total y un valor de alerta mínimo.

```
 select el.barCode, emo.name, SUM(bs.quantity) as total, av.quantity as alert
 from baseStock bs 
 left join element el on el.id_element = bs.id_element 
 left join elementModel emo on emo.id_elementModel = el.id_elementModel 
 left join alertValue av on av.id_base=bs.id_base and 
 av.id_elementModel=emo.id_elementModel 
 where bs.id_base = 41 
 and el.expireDate>GETDATE() 
 GROUP BY el.barCode, emo.name, av.quantity 
 order by el.barCode
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para traer solo los elementos cuyo total esté por debajo del valor de alerta mínimo? en el caso de la imagen solo debería traer el elemento marcado

Comment: Having es la clausula para condicionar los resultados despues del group by ;)

Comment: if else es otra posibilidad

Comment: @Iria `if else` no hace mucho sentido aquí

Comment: @Iria como usaria un if en este caso?

Comment: Se podría, pero sería más codigo y una consulta más. Es contraproducente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sería así, si los `JOIN` que incluyes son correctos.

```
 SELECT el.barCode, emo.name, SUM(bs.quantity) as total, av.quantity as alert 
 FROM baseStock bs 
    LEFT JOIN element el ON el.id_element = bs.id_element 
    LEFT JOIN elementModel emo ON emo.id_elementModel = el.id_elementModel 
    LEFT JOIN alertValue av ON av.id_base = bs.id_base 
 WHERE av.id_elementModel = emo.id_elementModel 
    AND bs.id_base = 41 
    AND el.expireDate > GETDATE()
 GROUP BY el.barCode, emo.name, av.quantity 
    HAVING SUM(bs.quantity) < av.quantity 
 ORDER BY el.barCode
```

Básicamente necesitas la propiedad `HAVING` en tu consulta, espero que te sirva.